# MS SQL Server (2008 R2) Error 18452 with Access 2010

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on an Access accdb project and I have all my tables linked to MS SQL Server 2008 R2 via ODBC.

I have one screen with a sub form that always gives me this error message when I enter it:
[image]
I've done some research and it it supposed to be related to the server's authentication method, but if all my tables are linked the same way, why does it happen?

What's even more weird is that if I refresh my table's connections via the linked table manager, everything works fine for some time, and then I get the same error again. I look through my code to see if I play with any connection string, but I don't.

Any thought/ideas? Any (educated) guess you have will be appreciated :)

Thanks,

Yotam

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Start > Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2005 > SQL Server Management Studio`

Right-click the Server name, select `Properties > Security` 
Under `Server Authentication`, select `SQL Server` and `Windows Authentication` Mode.

The server must be stopped and re-started before this will take effect.